# Google Auto suggestion City mismatch when using in different regions

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-places

I integrated the `GoogleMaps SDK` to pick Location of place by AutoSuggestion, I am using `GMSAutocompleteViewController` to get city suggestions, with this location for city selected I want to search for hotels in our database.

But city is getting different name in different countries. For my App need to be internationally I need to get the same results everywhere across the world. ( using the `GMSAutocompleteViewController`)

Some cities in India are showing differently in other parts of the world.

**Eg.Mangaluru to Mangalore(old)**

I tried to put the App Language and Region and to English and UK respectively and also tried to apply some filter like below.

```
GMSAutocompleteViewController *acController = [[GMSAutocompleteViewController alloc] init];
acController.autocompleteFilter.country @"GB"
```

After applying filter only that country results coming.

Any suggestions to get same type results everywhere.?

I want to get the same city results getting for the same search everywhere.

Comment: is there any api you using to get city and its hotels ?

Comment: GMSAutocompleteViewController returns cityname lat, long etc. With these am fetching hotels using our own api.

Comment: just check the class of `GMSAutocompleteViewController`  class how you getting city and hotel ..it may be the api behind it.

Comment: Api can't be accessed with SDK only getting the callback in delegate method

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the filter for the country to get results everywhere.
Based on the documentation [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete):

> *`**language**`* — ***The language code, indicating in which language the results should be returned, if possible***. Searches are also biased to the selected language; results in the selected language may be given a higher ranking. See the [list of supported languages](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport) and their codes. Note that we often update supported languages so this list may not be exhaustive. If language is not supplied, the Place Autocomplete service will attempt to use the native language of the domain from which the request is sent.

For the same city result, unfortunately, currently you can use components to filter by country.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Need to find current country before applying that filter? Is't it?. also the results will get limited to that country only, right?